# No termino de conseguir usar el WebHook de HelpScout

Tags: php, api, controller, class, smarty

Estoy tratando de integrar un WebHook de HelpScout teniendo ya aplicado la API del mismo en un módulo de PrestaShop que estoy creando. El tema es que le pregunto a los del servicio técnico de HelpScout y no pueden ayudarme, me comentan que me mire las guías que tienen acerca de este tema, pero la verdad que ya estoy cansado de verlas y el WebHook sigue sin funcionar.

```
public function getcontent()
{
    session_start();

    $tabs = $this->getTabs();

    $apiResponse = $this->getApi();
    $data = $apiResponse['data'];
    $result = $apiResponse['result'];
    $error = $apiResponse['error'];

    if ($_GET['webhook'] == 'reload') {
        $webhook = $this->getWebHook();
    }

    $this->smarty->assign(array(
        'data' => $data,
        'customer' => $result,
        'email' => $_SESSION['email'],
        'id_order' => $_SESSION['id_order'],
        'action' => $_SESSION['action'],
        'error' => $error,
        'test' => $webhook,
        'tabs' => $tabs,
    ));

    $this->context->controller->addJS($this->_path . 'views/js/functions.js');
    $this->context->controller->addCSS($this->_path . 'views/css/global.css');

    return $this->display(__FILE__, '/views/templates/admin/checkOrder.tpl');
}

public function getWebHook()
{
    $webhook = new \HelpScout\Webhook('clave de seguridad');
    $api = $this->getApi();
    $conversationApi = $api['data'];
    if ($webhook->isValid()) {
        $eventType = $webhook->getEventType();
        switch ($eventType)
        {
            case 'convo.closed':
                $conversation = $webhook->getConversation();
                foreach ($conversationApi as $converApi) {
                    if ($converApi['id'] == $conversation['id']) {
                        header("Refresh:0");
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Aquí os dejo el código involucrado en la pregunta a ver si vosotros podéis ayudarme.

¡Muchas gracias de antemano!